# Why I can not initialize my variable in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, initialization, init

I'm freeze in my app. I want to create my own reports.js file using variables like a functions but I can not initialize it. I'm copying other ones already done in the template but I can't understand why mine is not working.

Here is the part where I call it into the head section.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   "use strict";

   App.init(); // Init layout and core plugins
   Plugins.init(); // Init all plugins
   FormComponents.init(); // Init all form-specific plugins

   Reports.init();

   $('#StartDate').pickadate({
     formatSubmit: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
     hiddenName: true
   });
});
```

When I run the site, the console shows 
**TypeError: Reports.init is not a function**

Now I'm going to share the report.js file:

```
var Reports = function () {

   "use strict";

   var form = $('form').attr('id');
   alert(form);
   /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
    * Employee Clock-In Clock-Out
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
   var EmployeeClocks = function(form) {
      // will do something
   }

   return {
       // main function to initiate reports
       init: function () {
          // EmployeeClocks();
       },
   };
}
```

Comment: might want to move that "Use strict" above the $(document). ready. if you place it at the top of your script you dont need to call it in each function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `()`. Your `Reports` now is a function, not a class. But this function *returns* the thing you want.

```
var Reports = function () { ... }()
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I had not noticed that in the others scripts!!

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   "use strict";

   App.init(); // Init layout and core plugins
   Plugins.init(); // Init all plugins
   FormComponents.init(); // Init all form-specific plugins

   // Reports.init();
   var reports = new Reports();
   reports.init();

   $('#StartDate').pickadate({
     formatSubmit: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
     hiddenName: true
   });
});
```

Comment: You defined a function constructor in report.js

Comment: thanks your help mate, I choose the other one just because is less code... ;)